# Linux C open() Failing

Tags: c, linux, file, path

**My file open() keeps failing.** The program accepts an argument of a filename. The executable is right next to my test file "file.txt".

```
./runProgram file.txt 
ERROR - open() failed: Invalid argument
```

**The thing is the argument is a string, and I can printf() it just fine. So I'm not sure why it's an invalid argument...** I'm trying to open a file so I can get the system's pathname limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Pathname limit according to <limits.h> is: %i\n", PATH_MAX);

    int inputFD;//file descriptor to open the file

    //check and make sure that the user gave us the file name
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - No file name argument!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

    inputFD = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if(inputFD == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR - open() failed");
        return -1;
    }


    int fpcSize = fpathconf(inputFD, PATH_MAX);//return value from fpathconf

    if(fpcSize == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR - open() failed");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Path Size Limit: %i\n", fpcSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `open()`, not your `fpathconf()` failed? You use the same error message for both, somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your `open()` call that fails, it's your `fpathconf()` call which (perhaps by accident) produces the same error message. And the error message is telling because you actually use the wrong macro in the argument to `fpathconf()`: the macros for `fpathconf()` all begin with `_PC_`, `PATH_MAX` is the *default value* for the maximum path size, not the key for that attribute. The key macro is called `_PC_PATH_MAX`:

```
fpathconf(inputFD, _PC_PATH_MAX);
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something... Thanks so much for catching that!